# Force specific URL to be HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, iframe

For a website, we currently just switched over to SSL completely (all urls use HTTPS). We didn't realize until now but we have an iFrame that hosts a video on it where the iFrame makes a call to an un-secure script on their end.

We want to be able to disable HTTPS on this particular url and change it to HTTP. The url is https://www.website.com/media/{name-of-media-here}. The name of the media changes based on the media name. The iFrame are on all of these media pages.

In our .htaccess file we currently have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I've tried targeting the media slug and rewriting it to HTTP with no luck, then again I am no server guru so I probably had the rewrite rule written out incorrectly.

I'm currently trying this but it isn't working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/media/$1 [R,L]
```

What kind of rewrite rule do I need to target all /media/{whatever} domains and change it to http://www.website.com/media/{whatever}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/media/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /media/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache when testing it.